# Chart.js unwanted canvas resizing

Tags: javascript, canvas, resize, chart.js, scale

I'm drawing a chart to an in-memory canvas with strictly defined width and height, I'm then converting this canvas to base 64 using `toDataUrl()`. Everything was working fine until I use my code on a high density screen (Full HD notebook), where the Windows' **Display, Scale and Layout > Change the size of text, apps, and other items** option was at 125%, with this config, Chart.js is automatically resizing my canvas to 125% of its original size.

Is this a bug or a feature that I can disable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the option you need is [`devicePixelRatio`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/device-pixel-ratio.html), which will:

> Override the window's default devicePixelRatio.

I've not tested it, and the documentation isn't 100% clear, but I assume this goes in the root of the `options` object:

```
options: {
  devicePixelRatio: 1
}
```